# SupportMapFragment is invisible

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to programmatically create a SupportMapFragment to place it inside a tab.  It seems to create just fine (onCreateView(...) gets called getMap() returns a non-null value, etc...) but it doesn't actually render anything on the screen (as in I can only see the background image of the partent activity).

I've tried following the example from Google on nested fragments by doing:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, mapFragment).commit();
```

And I've tired subclassing SupportMapFragment but unless I place it in the xml layout file (i.e. using <fragment ... />), it won't display anything on the screen.  Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

I'm building for 2.3, targeting 4.2, and using the v12 support library, if it matters.  This is all being tested on a 4.0.3 device.

Comment: (I'd answer my own question but it won't let me)So it ended up being just a stupid mistake, I'm not sure why it didn't appear sooner.  I was only adding the fragment via transaction.add(fragment, tag) and forgot to specify the container id.  Only after I started to remove the nested fragment did the error start to show up.